# DET is $VQP-complete$ and also $DET\in VP$ Does that mean $VP=VQP$

Tags: complexity-classes, algebraic-complexity

We know that $DET$ is in $VP$. And also from https://conferences.mpi-inf.mpg.de/adfocs-17/material/MB_LN.pdf I came to know that $DET$ is $VQP-complete$. Now certainly $VP\subseteq VQP$. That implies $VP=VQP$. But there must be something wrong I am deducing but I can't find it. Where I am wrong?

Comment: It is VQP-complete but for different reductions than for VP (for VQP, one is allowed to reduce $f_n$ to $g_{q(n)}$ where $q$ is $n^{O(\log(n))}$). Hence it does not imply $VP = VQP$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One is used to this kind of argument because of what happens in $P$ and $NP$. However, one has to go back to why it is the case in general. If $P \in B$ is $A$-complete **under $\prec$-reductions** and $B \subseteq A$ **and B is closed under $\prec$-reduction**, then $A = B$. Indeed, if $Q \in A$, then $Q \prec P$ since $P$ is $A$-complete. It follows $Q \in B$ since $P \in B$ and $B$ is closed under $\prec$-reductions.

The completeness of $DET$ for $VQP$ [1, Theorem 3] is under $qp$-projections [1, Definition 9] but $VP$ is **not** closed under $qp$-projection (it seems unlikely and actually has been proven unconditionally in [2, Corollary 8.8] where it is shown that $VP \neq VQP$). Hence your argument is not correct and algebraic complexity researcher still have work to do !

Observe that the completeness of $DET$ for both $VQP$ and $VP_{ws}$ comes from the same core argument: one can show that the polynomial computed by an algebraic branching program of size $s$ can be expressed as the determinent of an $s' \times s'$ matrix with $s'$ polynomial in $s$. Now, one can simulate any circuit of size $t$ in $VQP$ (resp. $VP_{ws}$) by an algebraic branching program of size quasi-polynomial (resp. polynomial) hence the completeness of $DET$.

As you can see, this works for $VQP$ under $qp$-reduction since the transformed circuit into algebraic branching program is of quasi-polynomial size in the original circuit.

## References

[1] Malod, G., & Portier, N. (2008). *Characterizing Valiant's algebraic complexity classes.* Journal of complexity, 24(1), 16-38.

[2] Bürgisser, P. (2000). *Completeness and reduction in algebraic complexity theory* (Vol. 7). Springer Science & Business Media.

Comment: How does closure under qp-projection imply VP=VNP? Isn't VQP equal to the closure of VP under qp-projections, or am I missing something?

Comment: You are right, I wrote that too quickly. Actually, we *know* that VP is not closed under qp-projection, this is proven in Bürgisser's book. I will edit the answer, thanks for having spotted that!